# Drop down button in Tkinter OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I need to update my list when I click the button to drop down list:

[image]

How can I bind the button to some function?

Comment: what have you tried so far? any code you can show?

Comment: Without you giving us a [mcve], it's very hard for anyone to show you how to add a new binding to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you're looking for is [`Activate`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Tkinter.OptionMenu.bind):

```
optmenu.bind('<Activate>', onactivate)
```

Your `onactivate` callback takes an `Activate` event, but you probably don't care about its attributes.

The second half of your problem is how to update the menu. To do this, you use the `menu` attribute, which is a [`Menu`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Tkinter.Menu) object, on which you can call [`delete`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Tkinter.Menu.delete) and [`add`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Tkinter.Menu.add) and whatever else you want. So, for example:

```
def onactivate(evt):
    menu = optmenu['menu']
    menu.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    menu.add_command(label='new choice 1')
    menu.add_command(label='new choice 2')
    menu.add_separator()
    menu.add_command(label='new choice 3')
    optvar.set('new choice 1')
```

(However, notice that, while `set`ting the var at the end does cause that to become the new default selection, and does show up in the menu header, it doesn't cause the selected item to be highlighted if the cursor isn't over any of the menu items. If you want that, it's tricky, so hopefully you don't.)

Answer (score 0):

`'<Activate>'` didn't work but i found `'<Button-1>'` and now it works.

```
optmenu.bind('<Button-1>', onactivate)
```

Thank you :)